# What Pascal procedure inserts \mathon and \mathoff?

Tags: math-mode, tex-core

TeX surrounds inline math formulae with `\mathon` and `\mathoff`, which appear to be nodes.  For instance, running TeX on `$ $\showlists\bye` gives

```
### horizontal mode entered at line 0
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
\mathon
\mathoff
spacefactor 1000
### vertical mode entered at line 0
prevdepth ignored
```

Where are those defined or documented?  Neither the string `mathon` nor `mathoff` appear in the source file [`tex.web`](http://tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Build/source/texk/web2c/tex.web) of TeX.

Comment: Look for *math_node* in the index of `tex.pdf` (`texdoc tex`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [`tex.web`](http://tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Build/source/texk/web2c/tex.web), you'll find

```
3826: @ @<Display math node |p|@>=
3827: begin print_esc("math");
3828: if subtype(p)=before then print("on")
3829: else print("off");
3830: if width(p)<>0 then
3831:   begin print(", surrounded "); print_scaled(width(p));
3832:   end;
3833: end
```

making it part of the "procedure `Display math node`. `\mathon` and `\mathoff` is a construction of printing `\math` and then a conditional `on` or `off` based on the "`subtype` of the math node".

Comment: This is only for printing the diagnostic messages.

Answer (score 6):

What do we know about `\mathon` and `\mathoff`?  They are displayed by `\showbox`, `\showlists` and in other situations where the contents of a box or of a typeset list are written to the terminal or the log file.  As can be read in paragraph "12. Displaying boxes", all these are implemented through the procedure `show_node_list`, which displays a node list (the data structure TeX uses to store typeset material).  Ignoring some important error checking, the procedure simply uses the piece of code called `@<Display node |p|@>;` for each node `p` in the list.  That piece of code is

```
@ @<Display node |p|@>=
if is_char_node(p) then print_font_and_char(p)
else  case type(p) of
  hlist_node,vlist_node,unset_node: @<Display box |p|@>;
  rule_node: @<Display rule |p|@>;
  ins_node: @<Display insertion |p|@>;
  whatsit_node: @<Display the whatsit node |p|@>;
  glue_node: @<Display glue |p|@>;
  kern_node: @<Display kern |p|@>;
  math_node: @<Display math node |p|@>;
  ligature_node: @<Display ligature |p|@>;
  penalty_node: @<Display penalty |p|@>;
  disc_node: @<Display discretionary |p|@>;
  mark_node: @<Display mark |p|@>;
  adjust_node: @<Display adjustment |p|@>;
  @t\4@>@<Cases of |show_node_list| that arise in mlists only@>@;
  othercases print("Unknown node type!")
  endcases
```

which dispatches the display to various other pieces of code depending on the type of node.  The names `\mathon` and `\mathoff` are hints that we should look at the case `math_node`.  So let's.

```
@ @<Display math node |p|@>=
begin print_esc("math");
if subtype(p)=before then print("on")
else print("off");
if width(p)<>0 then
  begin print(", surrounded "); print_scaled(width(p));
  end;
end
```

As Werner said in a comment, we see that TeX prints `\math` for math nodes, then either `on` or `off` depending on the subtype of the node.  It then also gives some details about the `\mathsurround`.

We now know what to look for: where are math nodes with a subtype of `before` or `after` (it turns out) created?  We find the function `new_math`

```
@p function new_math(@!w:scaled;@!s:small_number):pointer;
var p:pointer; {the new node}
begin p:=get_node(small_node_size); type(p):=math_node;
subtype(p):=s; width(p):=w; new_math:=p;
end;
```

which inserts a node with type `math_node` and subtype `s` in the current list, and find that it is used twice, when it is time to "finish math in text":

```
@<Finish math in text@>=
begin tail_append(new_math(math_surround,before));
cur_mlist:=p; cur_style:=text_style; mlist_penalties:=(mode>0); mlist_to_hlist;
link(tail):=link(temp_head);
while link(tail)<>null do tail:=link(tail);
tail_append(new_math(math_surround,after));
space_factor:=1000; unsave;
end
```

This is finally the code which inserts math nodes with subtype `before` and `after`, which are eventually displayed as `\mathon` and `\mathoff` (and have a width equal to the value of the `\mathsurround`).